# Get Documentation Search Results Programmatically

Tags: version-10, documentation

Currently I don't have access to Wolfram Workbench but would like to add my own pages to the documentation search results in Mathematica.

How might I most easily manually add pages to the documentation search?

**NOTE:** If this is to complex(or simply considered impractical), what might be the easiest way to get the Documentary search results through M so I could add additional results before displaying the output?

Comment: Do you want to add documentation pages for your own functions? Then [this section of the Workbench documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/documentationpaclets/index.html) is relevant.

Comment: @TeakeNutma Yes relevant.  Unfortunately I don't have workbench so I'm trying to link my own custom results into Mathematica.

Comment: @TeakeNutma This appears to almost be a duplicate https://github.com/jmlopez-rod/ApplicationMaker

Comment: Also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center and here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47602/how-to-write-documentation-in-wolfram-style?rq=1

Comment: The wolfram workbench is free now for all Mathematica users. https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/ It is really necessary to make documentation that integrates properly into the doc center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the follow to retrieve results

```
Get[$InstallationDirectory<>"\\AddOns\\Applications\\DocumentationSearch\\DocumentationSearch.m"];
DocumentationSearch`SearchDocumentation["test"]
```

The formatting I believe is stored in

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\10.0\SystemFiles\FrontEnd\StyleSheets\Wolfram\Reference.nb
```

Or

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory <> "\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\StyleSheets\\Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}]
```

So run `SystemOpen[""]`

Editing the code you get something like the following

```
NotebookPut@Notebook[{},
  ScreenStyleEnvironment -> "Working",
  WindowMargins -> {{0, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}, 
  WindowFrame -> "Normal", 
  DockedCells -> 
   FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"], 
  StyleDefinitions -> 
   FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory <> 
      "\\SystemFiles\\FrontEnd\\StyleSheets\\Wolfram", "Reference.nb"}]
  ]
```