# How do I add my own help pages to the in-built Wolfram documentation?

Tags: documentation

How do I add my own help pages to the in-built Wolfram documentation ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center, and at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47602/how-to-write-documentation-in-wolfram-style

Comment: I haven't written documentation myself, but I have been looking into it for some time. It seems to me that the consensus is that the easiest path by far would be to use [Wolfram Workbench](http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/) if you have access to it.

Comment: Thanks, getting JLink errors in Workbench. Seems far too messy to accomplish anything using Workbench - may simply keep code snippets etc in "CodeBox" or similar. Thanks again for suggestions.

Comment: Do you need documentation for your package or you want to be able to add a custom page (e.g. guide) to the do docs? It would be nice to be able to achieve the latter.

Comment: I am able to add documentation for my own functions using the Workbench - no JLink errors.

Answer (score 2):

Possible in Wolfram Workbench:
http://www.wolfram.com/products/workbench/features/author.html

Comment: many thanks - I find Workbench clunky, basically unpleasant to use.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ApplicationMaker](https://github.com/jmlopez-rod/ApplicationMaker) package.