# How to generate docs for your package?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, packages, documentation, workbench

I don't have Wolfram Workbench, is there any other simple way to build documentation notebooks (like the built in documentation) for your custom packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to write documentation in Wolfram Style?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47602/14303)

Comment: @jkuczm I saw that one, definitely related, but I'm not asking to emulate the style, I'd like to access the underlying toolset.

Comment: As far as I know the toolset are 4 packages: ``DocumentationBuild` ``, ``DocumentationTools` ``, ``Transmogrify` `` and ``WorkbenchDocumentation` ``, but I've not seen them distributed in any other way than with Wolfram Workbench.

Comment: In version 10 there are new Template Notebooks which one might be able to make us of to accomplish this

Comment: Have you seen [Integrating notebooks to Mathematica's documentation center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center)