# How to make notebooks suitable for the Documentation Center?

Tags: documentation, workbench

Normally, documentation meant to be integrated into the Documentation Center is built from special source notebooks.

According to the Workbench documentation, it should also be possible to use [alternative formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/topic/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/documentationpaclets/alternative.html).  Just create the notebooks and put them at the specified location.  They will be copied over during documentation build and they will get a suitable URI for the Documentation Center.

I tried this and it works, but there are some problems.  The biggest one is that pressing the Reload button opens the notebooks in a standard window instead of in a documentation window.

[image]

How should a notebook be prepared so that it properly integrates into the Documentation Center and is well-behaved there?

This question is specifically about simple notebooks that do not go through the documentation build process.

As a first test, I was simply building a license page, for which there is no standard template. But eventually I would like to use this for documentation in alternative formats, as I won't always have time to create standard format documentation.

---

**"What have you tried?"**

The toolbar source can be examined using

```
FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"]
```

The button seems to invoke the [Revert](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/frontendobject/Revert.html) front end token, i.e. it's similar to (the same as?) File -> Revert...  This explains the behaviour I see but I still don't know why normal documentation notebooks don't behave this way.

I tried taking `StyleDefinitions` (which also adds the toolbar docked cell) and `TaggingRules` from a normally built doc notebook and trasferring them to my custom notebook. I manually edited the URIs to match.  The Revert button still re-opens the notebook in a new window.

Note that I am not asking for adding the help toolbar to the notebook. This can indeed by accomplished by ensuring that the notebook or its stylesheet has `` DockedCells -> FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"] ``.  But the Reload button will still open a new window which, while it does have the help toolbar, isn't the same as the documentation browser.  There are clear differences:

- The doc browser disappears and the notebook window appear at a new position on screen
- The notebook window doesn't show "- Wolfram Mathematica 10.0" in the title bar
- When using the search toolbar in the notebook window, it will open a new doc browser instead of showing the results in the same window
- The Back button doesn't work

What I want is to stay within the documentation browser and not open a separate notebook.

---

[Cross posted on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/972143)

Comment: You need `Saveable -> False` option on your notebook, in addition to some style definitions adding `"HelpViewerToolbar"` e.g. ``StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[
        {Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],
            DockedCells ->
                FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"]
        ]},
        StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"
    ]``

Comment: @jkuczm This doesn't fix the problem I mentioned though.

Comment: I updated the main post to clarify why this doesn't work. It adds the toolbar, but doesn't really prevent escaping the documentation brwoser.

Comment: @jkuczm Actually you're right. But the only option that is needed is `Saveable -> False`.  The stylesheet is not needed (maybe it's a nice to have). Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Related: [How to write documentation in Wolfram Style?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47602/14303), [Integrating notebooks to Mathematica's documentation center](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6574710/5400699)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For notebook to stay in the same place, after `Revert` action, it needs `Saveable -> False` option.

Note: A notebook with `Saveable -> False` cannot be saved using the GUI through File -> Save...  It can be saved programmatically using `NotebookSave`, or exported using `Export[..., "NB"]`, etc.

---

Let's create basic test application with documentation support:

```
appName = "docNotebookTest";
appPath = FileNameJoin@{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", appName};
nbPath = FileNameJoin@{appPath, "Documentation", "English", "altDoc", "test.nb"};
CreateDirectory@DirectoryName@nbPath
Export[FileNameJoin@{appPath, "PacletInfo.m"},
    Paclet[Name -> appName, Version -> "0.0.1",
        Extensions -> {{"Documentation", Language -> "English"}}
    ]
]
```

Now create simple un-`Saveable` notebook and restart paclet manager, so that it can find our new documentation notebook:

```
Export[nbPath,
    Notebook[{Cell["Contents of alternative documentation notebook.", "Text"]},
        Saveable -> False
    ]
]
RestartPacletManager[]
```

Now if we go to documentation center and search for `docNotebookTest/altDoc/test`, we'll get our example notebook open in the same window with `"HelpViewerToolbar"`. You can click on reload button and notebook will remain in the same place and it'll retain `"HelpViewerToolbar"`. Close this test documentation notebook for now, so it won't interfere with further tests.

I don't know internals of mechanism behind this, but the fact that toolbar stays there feels a bit accidental. "Ordinary" documentation notebook appears with `"HelpViewerToolbar"` no matter how you open it e.g.:

```
NotebookOpen@"paclet:ref/List"
```

Opens `List` documentation notebook with `"HelpViewerToolbar"` on. This is because it uses `` StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"] `` and `Reference.nb` style-sheet has:

```
Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"],
    DockedCells->FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"]
]
```

as one of declarations.

If we open our notebook in any other way than searching in documentation center:

```
nbObj = NotebookOpen@"paclet:docNotebookTest/altDoc/test"
```

it opens *without* `"HelpViewerToolbar"` (if you didn't close `test.nb` previously opened through documentation center, then above command will just make its window, with toolbar, active).

If we want our notebook to always open with `"HelpViewerToolbar"`, as "ordinary" documentation notebooks do, we should add this toolbar to notebook `DockedCells`, either directly, or through o style-sheet:

```
nbObj // NotebookClose
Export[nbPath,
    Notebook[{Cell["Contents of alternative documentation notebook.", "Text"]},
        Saveable -> False,
        DockedCells ->
            FEPrivate`FrontEndResource["FEExpressions", "HelpViewerToolbar"]
    ]
]
```

Now our notebook always opens with desired toolbar:

```
nbObj = NotebookOpen@"paclet:docNotebookTest/altDoc/test"
```

Close notebook and delete our test application:

```
nbObj // NotebookClose
DeleteDirectory[appPath, DeleteContents -> True]
```

Comment: It also seems useful to use the Doc Center stylesheet. This adds the search toolbar, and has other useful effects as well: it makes text and section cells non-editable while retaining the ability to add/edit/delete input and output cells.